# Exportar datatable para PDF

Tags: java, primefaces

Estou usando Java,JPA,Primefaces,Wildfly, tenho uma datatable que preciso exportar para PDF,no excel é só adicionar o poi.jar que funciona mas no PDF não sei qual poi que devo adicionar, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `<p:dataExporter>`:

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable id="tbl" var="car" value="#{dataExporterView.cars}">

        <f:facet name="{Exporters}">
            <h:commandLink>
                <p:graphicImage name="/demo/images/pdf.png" width="24"/>
                <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="tbl" fileName="cars"/>
            </h:commandLink>
        </f:facet>

        <!-- colunas -->

    </p:dataTable>
<h:form>
```

Você pode exportar para diversos outros formatos, inclusive XLS. É só mudar a propriedade `type` para `type=xls`.

---

**EDIT:**

Para a exportação para PDF funcionar você deve incluir a biblioteca`iText` no seu projeto.

Para a exportação para XLS funcionar você deve incluir a biblioteca `apache poi` no seu projeto.

---

Mais informações no [site do PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/basic.xhtml).

Comment: Este trexo é exaamente como esta no site do primefaces,inclusive estou usando desta forma, mas para utilizar precisa de um poi, eu adicionei esse jar par ausar o exel mas nao seu qual é o do PDF

Comment: Pelo o que entendi você precisa adicionar uma lib chamada `iText` também.

Comment: voce sabe me dizer qual é a versão desta lib que devo tomar como parametro?

Comment: Pode ser a versão 2.1.7

Comment: consegui, deu certo, esta é a versao correta, Obrigado